# Title: CORS Issue with Handlebars Email Templating in Node Express: Works in Dev but Throws 502 Bad Gateway in Prod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm encountering a CORS issue with my Node Express backend and React frontend setup. I have implemented CORS with a list of allowed origins in my backend, and it works fine in development. However, when I switched from normal HTML email templating to Handlebars, I started getting a 502 Bad Gateway CORS error in production.

Here's a snippet of my CORS setup in the backend:

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  'https://localhost:3000',
  'http://localhost:3000',
  'https://dev.example.example.com',
  'https://example.example.com',
  'https://example.example.com:3000',
  'https://www.example.example',
  'https://www.example.example:3000',
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error(messages.CORS_ERROR));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The issue arises only in production after switching to Handlebars for email templating. In development, everything works as expected.

Expected Result:

The application should work without CORS issues in both development and production, even with Handlebars for email templating.

Comment: if you're getting a 502 Bad Gateway, then no amount of fiddling with the server will fix that, since the Gateway issuing the response is not your server - I take it `example.example` is a placeholder for the domain serving the web page, i.e. you have one server for the react App (HTML, JS, etc) and one for your API - and it's the API server that configuration is on